# Redirect the outputs and still see them when running a bash script

Tags: bash, redirect, exec

My sysadmin created a bash script and the first command in it is to redirect the output in a log file:

```
exec > my_app.log
```

With this, I have the following:

- `stdout` redirected to `my_app.log`
- see `stderr` live in my terminal

When I manually execute the script, I want all of the following:

- `stdout` redirected to `my_app.log`
- `stderr` redirected to `my_app.err`
- see `stdout` live in my terminal
- see `stderr` live in my terminal

What do I need to change to the exec to have all that to happen?

Currently what I do is open 3 terminals.

- one to run the script with `./my_script.sh 2> my_app.err`
- one to use `tail -f my_app.log`
- one to use `tail -f my_app.err`

This is too much I think.

Comment: [`man tee`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee)

Answer (score 2):

echo `"hello" | tee file.txt`

output from `echo "hello"` put to the file and stdout

if you need stderr and stdout, then `echo "hello" 2>&1 | tee file.txt`